# Why is it called General Purpose Processor

Tags: processor

I need some help to understand the name "general prupose processor". Through my search I read that a GPP is a:

- General-Purpose Microprocessors (Hardware....)
- General-Purpose Macroprocessors (a computer program, Preprocessor?)

So I think that the name should say, it is used generally everywhere (Hardware and Software). 
Am I right ? By the way, is a PC CPU also a GPP ?

Comment: In the future, you may not want to accept the first answer so quickly.  You might get a better answer given a little more patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"General purpose" means it is not designed for any specialized purpose.
Some examples of processors that are not General Purpose are:

- Graphics Processing Units (GPUs) are highly parrallelized to run a large number of geometric solutions (transforms, triangle clipping, etc.) to create frame
  buffers for video images very quickly.
- Floating-point Processing Units (FPUs) are highly specialized to
  execute floating point math.  This is typically a subsystem of modern PC processors.
- Digital Signal Processors (DSPs) have
  specialized instructions and large accumulator registers to do very quick multiply and accumulate operations.
- Embedded Processors contain integrated peripherals such
  as USB controllers, Ethernet MACs, serial ports, etc. to reduce both power consumption
  and the required space for electronics so every device we carry
  around doesn't have to be the size of a PC motherboard.

To answer your second question, yes.  A PC's CPU is a General Purpose Processors since it is designed for general computing applications.

A macro processor is one of the functions of a preprocessor.  It is piece of software that replicates a string of text throughout the source code before the source code is compiled to aid in readability and source code maintenance.

Comment: I agree with you definition in general, but I don't think the embedded processor definition fits.  You're defining an SoC (which many embedded processor are), which is a GPP plus peripherals on one chip.  By that definition, an embedded processor IS a GPP (or at least it contains one).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a PC CPU is a "General Purpose Processor." It's general purpose because it's designed to be fairly good at nearly any task you could want to do with a processor - including branch prediction to make conditionals faster and layered caches to make memory access faster.

To give you an idea of a non-general-purpose processor: GPUs.

These are particularly bad at conditionals (if(x)y();else z()) and so most programs that we use every day (like your web browser: if(tag.name=="html")...) are very poorly suited for them.

Furthermore, things which access memory randomly and all over the place suffer bigger hits because the onboard cache isn't optimized for such actions.

In exchange for not putting beefy caches and branch-prediction, they can use more transistors to make mathematical-related operations considerably faster ("multiply these 100,000 floating-point numbers by twoPi").